# Changing public folder on Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I've just started (re)learning Laravel, now on this version 8, and working with a Apache Server (Xampp) that runs lots of other web applications (a server machine that run some essential internal services and APIs) and was thinking if it was possible to just put the public folder on the htdocs, so it's accessible, and the application outside of it.

I've been using CodeIgniter 4.1.1 lately and was a tricky part to learn but now is rather simple to do, just changing one or two references inside the index.php code and it's done, how would it be done on Laravel 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bring public folder out of the project than you need to change the dir path inthe index.php file:

from

```
   require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: A more "generic" to it, is just edit the above mentioned lines to find the autoload and bootstrap/app, so you can put your public folder wherever you want, as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove public from your app URL then you place your index.php and .htaccess to the root folder and The following change in index.php

from

```
  require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
  $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```