# When deploying laravel 8 on server it shows folder structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When deploying Laravel 8 on Hostinger Shared Hosting and on localhost via XAMPP server, it shows root folder structure and works fine on local when serving via

```
php artisan serve
```

I tried to add .htaccess in the root but nothing happens, it still shows folder structure.

Tried this one [Changing public folder on Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132251/changing-public-folder-on-laravel-8) but nothing happens.

Comment: it's not recommended to host Laravel apps on shared hosting. Still if you want check this https://medium.com/backenders-club/how-to-host-a-laravel-project-on-a-shared-hosting-via-cpanel-d955d32c528e

Comment: The website root needs to be the `public` folder so you should configure your shared hosting to reflect this. You don't need your own .htaccess file if you do this since Laravel ships with its own

Comment: nginx is better